# It is possible to skip a chracter from fnsymbols?

Tags: footnotes, renewcommand

I'm changing the marks of the footnotes using the following line of code, but I didn't want to use the asterisk as a mark.

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
```

Is possible to remove the asterisk and keep using the fnsymbols? Or is possible to do something like the follow line of code, where is add 1 to the counter?

```
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote+1}}
```

Answer (score 2):

`\fnsymbol` is defined in the latex format via

```
\def\@fnsymbol#1{%
   \ifcase#1\or \TextOrMath\textasteriskcentered *\or
   \TextOrMath \textdagger \dagger\or
   \TextOrMath \textdaggerdbl \ddagger \or
   \TextOrMath \textsection  \mathsection\or
   \TextOrMath \textparagraph \mathparagraph\or
   \TextOrMath \textbardbl \|\or
   \TextOrMath {\textasteriskcentered\textasteriskcentered}{**}\or
   \TextOrMath {\textdagger\textdagger}{\dagger\dagger}\or
   \TextOrMath {\textdaggerdbl\textdaggerdbl}{\ddagger\ddagger}\else
   \@ctrerr \fi
}%
```

so it's just a simple list of commands separated by `\or`  you could define  that to be any sequence you like.